# Writing filter() function but getting typeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

my code consists of me recreating the function 'filter()' and using it with a function to filter words longer than 5 characters. It worked with the actual function filter when I tried it btw...I'm using python 3+

```
def filter1(fn, a):
    i = 0
    while i != len(a):
        u = i - 1
        a[i] = fn(a[i], a[u])
        i += 1
    return a


def filter_long_words(l):
    if len[l] > 5:
        return [l]

listered = ['blue', 'hdfdhsf', 'dsfjbdsf', 'jole']
print(list(filter1(filter_long_words, listered)))
```

getting error

```
TypeError: filter_long_words() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What is `a[i] = fn(a[i], a[u])` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two parameters to `fn` (which refers to `filter_long_words`) here:

```
a[i] = fn(a[i], a[u])
```

But `filter_long_words` only accepts one parameter.

Notes:

- You can loop through lists using `for item in my_list`, or if you want index as well `for index, item in enumerate(my_list)`.
- I think you might get an `IndexError` since `u` will be `-1` in the first round of your loop.
- The `filter` function can also be expressed as a list comprehension: `(item for item in listered if filter_long_words(item))`

My version of `filter` would look like this, if I have to use a `for` loop:

```
def my_filter(fn, sequence):
    if fn is None:
        fn = lambda x: x
    for item in sequence:
        if fn(item):
            yield item
```

Since you have stated that you are using Python 3, this returns a generator instead of a list. If you want it to return a list:

```
def my_filter(fn, sequence):
    if fn is None:
        fn = lambda x: x
    acc = []
    for item in sequence:
        if fn(item):
            acc.append(item)
    return acc
```

If you don't need to use a `for` loop:

```
def my_filter(fn, sequence):
    if fn is None:
        fn = lambda x: x
    return (item for item in sequence if fn(item))
```

Comment: So how exactly should the new filter() look using a for loop??

Answer (score 1):

Your're calling `fn` with 2 parameters in `filter1(fn, a)`, and since you've passed `filter_long_words()` to `filter1` as `fn`, that triggers the error.

But there's more weird stuff:

I don't understand the magick of `filter1` or what you were trying to
accomplish, but it seems to me that you don't have a clear idea what to do.
But if you want to mimic (somehow) how `filter` works, you have to return a
list which contains only items for which the `fn` function returns true. When
you know this, you can rewrite it - here are a few suggestions for rewrite

```
# explicit, inefficient and long, but straightforward version:
def filter1(fn, a):
    new_list = []
    for item in a:
        if fn(item):
            new_list.append(item):
    return new_list

# shorter version using list comprehensions:
def filter1(fn, a):
    return [item for item in a if fn(item)]
```

The `filter_long_words` function is wrong too - it should return True or
False. The only reason why it could work is because any non-empty list is
treated as `True` by python and default return value of a function is `None`,
which translates to False. But it's confusing and syntactically wrong to use
`len[l]` - the proper usage is `len(l)`.
There are a few suggestions for rewrite, which all returns explicit boolean
values:

```
# unnecessary long, but self-explanatory:
def filter_long_words(l):
    if len(l) > 5:
        return True
    else
        return False

# short variant
def filter_long_words(l):
    return len(l) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling  "filter_long_words" with 2 parameter => fn(a[i], a[u]) also there is an error

```
def filter_long_words(l):
    if **len[l]** > 5:
        return [l]
```

len is builtin method it should be len(l)